# print first 3 lines of a file using system function write

Tags: c, operating-system, fwrite

I am trying to print the first 3 lines using the system function write in [c](/questions/tagged/c).

I have the following code:

```
ssize_t wresult = 0; 
ssize_t res;
ssize_t rresult = 0;
char buff[1];
int count = 0;

while((rresult = read(fd, buff,1))!= 0 ) 
{
    while(wresult != rresult){
        ssize_t res = 0;
        res = write(STDOUT_FILENO,buff+wresult,rresult-wresult);
        if(res < 0) return -1;
        wresult += res;
        count++;
        if(count == 3) break;
    }
}
```

However, the output is not what I want - it outputs the whole file (more than 10 lines). 
How do I print **just** the **first 3 lines**.

Comment: Are you in anywhere in your code **incrementing** `count` after initializing it to`0` for it to reach the value `3`?

Comment: You've just created a miracle! How can anything be written when you shouldn't even enter your while-loop? `wresult` and `rresult` equal eachother from the start!

Comment: Sorry, the file is opened before that, so they are indeed changed, will add it.

Comment: your read function is just getting one character.  have you tried using the `getline` function that will read a line at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `write()` will write a number of bytes to file (or stdout). You need to figure out where the end of the lines are.

There are a number of problems from the code you have here. The variable `count` is not being set to any value and so it will always be 0.

Also, from the code you have here you're reading from a 1 byte buffer. That would cause a crash.

Comment: So I guess I should increment count when I reach a new line, right? How do I know when I have hit a new line?

Comment: Yes, what you have as `count` (which could also be named something like `numlines`) should be incremented for every new line.

Comment: It might be easier to figure out from the source buffer/file how many bytes until the end of 3 lines and then do one write().

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Well, first of all where are you getting your buffer from? In the code above it's a 1 byte array with no data set in it

Comment: You could iterate on the source buffer until you find 3 newline characters

Comment: Mark my answer as resolved if it helps. Will step away for a while now

Comment: ... and we never saw him again... 